# Did Jesus ever sing?

Tags: life-of-jesus, music, jesus-christ-superstar

I've been re-watching Jesus Christ Superstar recently and a thought sprang into my mind: did the real Jesus ever sing? I mean, are there any records to that effect in the Scriptures or elsewhere, perhaps, in apocryphal texts, Coptic texts, etc.

Comment: Sorry @MarcGravell, beat you to it by just four minutes. :)

Comment: @Wikis no problem ;p

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes. [Matthew 26:30](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+26:30&version=NIV) and [Mark 14:26](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark+14:26&version=NIV) both state:

> When **they had sung a hymn**, they went out to the Mount of Olives.

*"They"* here refers to Jesus and His disciples. It occurred immediately after The Last Supper.

Answer (score 0):

It is believed that Jesus taught the Our Father prayer in verses-- verses which perfectly rhymed. Jack Kilmon, the Bible scholar did  a retro-translation of the prayer into Aramaic,  the language which Jesus spoke, and came out with the astonishing finding that it indeed was a beautiful poem, which Jesus must have sung and His disciples repeated.

(P.S.: Please visit 'Scriptorium' hosted by Jack Kilmon to know more. )

Comment: Kilmon page http://www.historian.net/lp-pap2.html. If you add that to your answer and maybe summarize and/or quote a short passage, it would greatly improve the quality of your answer.